# For loop : variable not taken into account

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, variables, set

I have a problem with the batch script below when checking the write permissions on the target folders.

It works well if there are only write-protected folders. But if there are a mix of write-protected folders and non-write-protected folders, it will also run xcopy for the write-protected folders.

I think it has to do with the value assigned to "write_ok" that always keeps the last value.

But how can I fix it ?

Here is my code :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set BackupDest=D:\backup

for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /a:d-h /b "%HomeDrive%\users\*" ^| findstr /x /i /l /v /g:"%~dp0exclude_users.txt"') do if exist "%BackupDest%\%%I\" (

echo -----------------------------------------
echo      Processing user : %%I
echo -----------------------------------------
echo

:: checking write permissions
copy /y nul "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable" >nul 2>&1 && set write_ok=1
if defined write_ok (
del "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable"

xcopy "%%I\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Desktop\" /e /i /y
xcopy "%%I\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Documents\" /e /i /y

) else (
echo       Access refused ^(check permissions^)
)
)

pause
exit
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you forgot to undefine `write_ok`, so once it's defined, it keeps being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to unset the `write_ok` variable, so after once it's set, it is always defined.
Just unset it before using it:

```
:: checking write permissions
set "write_ok="
copy /y nul "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable" >nul 2>&1 && set write_ok=1
if defined write_ok (
  del "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable"
  xcopy "%%I\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Desktop\" /e /i /y
  xcopy "%%I\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Documents\" /e /i /y
) else (
  echo       Access refused ^(check permissions^)
)
```

Alternatively you can avoid the variable completely:

```
:: checking write permissions
copy /y nul "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable" >nul 2>&1 && (
  del "%BackupDest%\%%I\.writable"
  xcopy "%%I\Desktop" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Desktop\" /e /i /y
  xcopy "%%I\Documents" "%BackupDest%\%%I\Documents\" /e /i /y
) || (
  echo       Access refused ^(check permissions^)
)
```